# Should I buy a new HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, ctrl-alt-delete

It's been months since I've been receiving "A disk read error occurred. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart" error and I don't know exactly why. This error occurs minimum 2-3 times a week and the only solution I find to remove is to wait for sometime and restart my computer again and again for at least 5-6 times. Now I'm a bit confused that whether this problem is associated with my HDD only or some other hardware too.

Also, even if my computer starts and works in its normal phase it lags a LOT! even with programs like Chrome.

PC Specs:

- Operating System: Windows 8.1 64-bit
- Motherboard: Gigabyte B85M-DS3H
- Memory: 8192MB RAM
- Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
- HardDisk: 500 GB

I basically use my computer for video editing with softwares like AfterEffects, Premiere pro etc.

Comment: If it's happening randomly, your hard drive has bad sectors and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Buy a 500GB ssd. Life will be wonderful. You'll wonder why you didn't do it sooner.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe. You really ought to talk to your hard drive first, ask it how its feeling and all that.

[gsmartctl](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/Downloads) is my tool of choice - run a short test, if that fails runs a long test. If it fails either, get a new drive as a system drive.

Before I do that, I'd also give a cursory look at the smart attributes there too - wikipedia's entry on [S.M.A.R.T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) highlights the important stuff to look at. From what you're saying reallocated sector count and pending reallocated sector counts should be what you'd look that - in my experience this is the sort of thing that would fail in a situation like this, and it would also explain the slowdown, as your drive is consistently needing to work around badblocks.

Comment: +1 for the 'talk to your hard drive' :) I really like it when people explain like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's either buy a new hard drive or see if it behaves better on another operating system (e.g. Linux or OS X) which may handle faulty hardware differently/better. I assume this is not an option for you since you use windows bound software.

Your hard drive is obviously failing, did you really have to ask? Of course you should replace a failing hard drive! It's up to you if you want to wait for it to fully crash or not though.

Comment: Life is too short to waste your time dealing with faulty hardware. Toss it, and get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There may be chances that you have installed any software or application which may have virus in it. I suggests that try to uninstall that application and restart your system to overcome this issue. If you still feel the same problem, then you should run CHKDSK command to check your hard drive health. Good Luck!!!